# Call a suspend apiFetch request in Firebase onMessageReceived when the app in background/killed

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Firebase notifications to fetch changes from the server. The server sends the fcm notification when there is any change in the data. Here is the code:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    val res = p0.data
    val noti = p0.notification
    val id: String? = res["id"]
    val title: String? = noti.title
    val body: String? = noti.body

    id.toInt().let {
       GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
          try {
             var isActive = true
             res["is_active"].let{st->
                st?.let{act->
                   if(act == "false"){
                       isActive = false
                   }
                }
             }
             projRepo.roomChangeActiveStatus(it, isActive)
         } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {                           
             FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
         }
      }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine when the app is in foreground and It shows notification when the app is in background/killed but its not calling the GlobalScope function when the app is in background/killed.

Comment: Because Global Scope Coroutines live as long as your Application is not destroyed. And when the Application is not running, Global Scope cannot be run. Also There is no need to do the tasks on IO Thread as Service already runs in background with its own lifecycle.

Comment: So, how to call the Repo function as these are suspended functions

Comment: Use CoroutineScope(Dispatcher.IO).launch {} instead.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal Its not working when the app is in background/killed

Comment: What are you doing in Repository?. Remember you can't make network requests from Services, you should use Workers to do that. I had the same issue, I solved it using Workers and if you find any better solution please let me know too.

Comment: Found out that we can call the network requests when sending notifications as data messages